# Jquery AJAX get new mysql records in real time

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, twitter

Is there any twitter-like solution for retrieving new mysql records using PHP in real-time and having them slide down

Thanks,

Answer (score 4):

Try like this

```
$(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",

            url: "location/of/server/script.php",
            success: function(html) {
                 // html is a string of all output of the server script.
                $("#element").html(html);
           }

        });
    }, 5000);
});
```

It will update on every 5 seconds.

This is only an example script,fadein effects can be added after the sucess .Hope it helps

Comment: please also provide mysql query to fetch records from database :\

Answer (score 1):

i would recommend you to read about websockets if you really want real-time updating. otherwise you could use the jquery setInterval.

**websockets:**

[probably the best one](http://nodejs.org/)

you can find lots of tuts on the web:

[results](https://www.google.de/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ix=sea&ie=UTF-8#hl=de&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=websocket%20tutorial&oq=&aq=&aqi=&aql=&gs_l=&pbx=1&fp=5e4b47d4c544e1de&ix=sea&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&biw=1280&bih=963)

Answer (score 0):

If you really want real-time, you're going to want the notifications to be "pushed" to the client, not polled.  To do this, on the client side you will probably want to use something like HTML5's "event source" to listen for events and update the UI.

On the server side, there isn't any way for mysql to notify PHP of new records, so you would likely want to use some kind of a message queue (like RabbitMQ or ActiveMQ).  You would have to modify the code that inserts into your database so that it also notifies your message queue.